# Pass parameters in RecycleViewer adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In the onCreateViewHolder method of the adapter, I have the `oprShown` variable that I need to be passed as a parameter.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_shift_container, parent, false);

    GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams)itemView.getLayoutParams();

    lp.width = parent.getMeasuredWidth()/oprShown;

    itemView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    return new ShiftViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

The constructor of the adapter is like below:

```
private Context context;

private List<ShiftModel> shiftModelList;

int oprShown;

public ShiftMapAdapter(Context context, List<ShiftModel> shiftModelList, int oprShown) {
    this.context = context;
    this.shiftModelList = shiftModelList;
    this.oprShown = oprShown;
}
```

Then I call everything like below:

```
int operatorShow = 6;
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    shiftsViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ShiftsViewModel.class);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shifts, container, false);

    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, root);

    initialize();

    shiftsViewModel.getCoworkerList().observe(this, new Observer<List<ShiftModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<ShiftModel> shiftModel) {
            ShiftMapAdapter shiftMapAdapter = new ShiftMapAdapter(getContext(), shiftModel, operatorShow);
            coworker_recycler.setAdapter(shiftMapAdapter);
        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

All I want to do is to make the width of the recycle view equal to 1/6 of the parent screen. But when I run the code I get this error:

> error: constructor ShiftMapAdapter in class ShiftMapAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: Context,List,int
>   found: Context,List
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Any help, please?

Comment: Can you check what getContext() is returningg?

Comment: @Swayangjit I'm calling it from a fragment, so getContext() returns a fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getActivity() instead of getContext()

```
ShiftMapAdapter shiftMapAdapter = new ShiftMapAdapter(getActivity(), shiftModel, operatorShow);
coworker_recycler.setAdapter(shiftMapAdapter);
```

Comment: Another question please, how to notify the adapter if I change the variable `operatorShow`

Comment: Either try notifyDataSetChanged() or reinitialize it .